# Deserializing a byte array in multiple pieces

Tags: c#, serialization

I have this function that splits a serialized byte array into pieces based on a max length:

```
public static List<byte[]> ZipStringList(List<string> curSpawn, int maxSize = -1) {
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
    MemoryStream o = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(o, curSpawn);
    byte[] buffer = o.GetBuffer();
    o.Close();

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    if (maxSize > 0 && memoryStream.Length > maxSize) {
        int pieces = Mathf.CeilToInt (memoryStream.Length / (float)maxSize);
        List<byte[]> listByte = new List<byte[]> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < pieces; ++i) {
            int curLength = (int)Mathf.Min (maxSize, memoryStream.Length - (i * maxSize));
            byte[] compressedData = new byte[curLength];
            memoryStream.Read (compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

            if (i == pieces - 1) {
                byte[] gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
                Buffer.BlockCopy (compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy (BitConverter.GetBytes (buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
                listByte.Add (gZipBuffer);
            }//if last piece
            else {
                listByte.Add (compressedData);
            }//else normal
        }//for each piece
        return listByte;
    } else {
        byte[] compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read (compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

        byte[] gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy (compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy (BitConverter.GetBytes (buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
        List<byte[]> retList = new List<byte[]> ();
        retList.Add (gZipBuffer);
        return retList;
    }
}//ZipStringList()
```

Then this function that deserializes it:

```
public static List<string> UnzipStringList(List<byte[]> byteList) {
    byte[] gZipBuffer = byteList.SelectMany(b => b).ToArray();

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "yes");
    byte[] buffer;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gZipBuffer, 0);
        memoryStream.Write(gZipBuffer, 4, gZipBuffer.Length - 4);

        buffer = new byte[dataLength];

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            gZipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }

    MemoryStream o = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    return (List<string>)bf.Deserialize(o);
}//UnzipStringList()
```

When I run it though, I'm getting a "corrupted gzip header" error, so there's some simple thing I'm missing. What is it?

More details: there aren't really, I'm likely positioning the buffer wrong. Fun fact: I searched google for the error message and the only result was this question.

Here's some code you can test with. Make it a large enough file (like at least a kilobyte). My file is full of JSON arrays.

```
    string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines ("path_to_file.txt");
    List<byte[]> byteArray = Utility.ZipStringList(new List<string>(allLines), 60000);
    List<string> stringList = Utility.UnzipStringList (byteArray);
    Utility.LogRealError ("I unzipped it?", stringList.Count, stringList [4]);
```

Comment: With which list of strings do you get the error? Works fine on my side after replacing Mathf class that I do not have by the regular Math class and some casting...

Comment: It's a 1.3kb file of JSON arrays and a max size set to 60,000. Happens with anything large enough to need splitting up. The error occurs at: gZipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Comment: Are you trying to split up a zip file and then unzip it in chunks?

Comment: It's just a regular text document of JSON strings, I'm trying to split it up into small enough pieces to get around a max buffer length and then combine those pieces back into its original string

Comment: Data is not stored sequentially in a zip file.  It is stored like a File Structure so data may not be continuous.  Reading only part of the files may not be enough to get your entire data.

Comment: I'm trying to read the full file, just splitting it up into smaller pieces, sending those pieces, then putting the pieces back together again on the other end